# Category is not working as well as products won't be displayed

Tags: magento2

I'm currently having the problem, that the categories and products are not working. I've added the categories as a sub category to "Default Category". I've checked if they are active or not as well as setting the quantitiy to 1 (or more).

The actual problem is that when I click a category in the navigation menu, nothing happens. The cms page get's refreshed and that's it.

I've added the "New Products" widget. The products are showing up but as soon as I click on them the cms page get's refreshed and nothing happens.

Typing the URL manually results in a 404 Error.

Reindexing has also been done.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hope u cleared cache, ran static content deploy cmd

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes I've done this. But it did not help.

Comment: Please run reindex command that may solve your problem

Comment: How about your current issue?

Comment: Not fixed yet unfortunately. Do you have the same solution instead for apache for ngix?